# Using output from field as url

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to write an application which takes a user input of a URL and then moves to the next view and uses that URL to load in a browser.

I've got the input page and think I've got it saving but unsure of how to use that data in the final view and load it in the browser - the method I tried just made the screen white - I've included a url where I want the input url to go - please see below code -

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  webView
//
//  Created by Yash Patel on 18/10/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Yash Patel. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import WebKit


class lockdownfield {
weak var lockdowntest: UITextField? {

    func viewDidLoad() {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(lockdownfield?.self, forKey: "lockdowntest")
}
return nil }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "http://tablet.brainsplurge.co.uk/video-playlists/lancome-selfridges-oxford-st-1/")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webview.load(request)
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Did you allow arbitrary loads in info.plist?

Comment: Yes, arbitrary loads are allowed - with the link entered in the code directly it works - I'm just trying to get it so essentially the first time you launch the app it asks for a URL - stores it and then takes you to the next view which loads the site you've just specified.  Then next time you launch the app it remembers the URL you've entered previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, somewhat similar to SAXENA's, but more complete.

ViewController1:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var urlTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //If user is opening the app the second time, then we just redirect him directly to the webView with the saved URL
        let secondLoad = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "secondLoad")
        if secondLoad == true {
            let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
            vc.userURL = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "userURL") as! URL
            self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func goToNextScreen(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        vc.userURL = URL(string: urlTextField.text!)
        //Save the URL for further usage
        UserDefaults.standard.set(userURL, forKey: "userURL")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        // if you don't have a navigationController embeded into your ViewController use this function instead
        //self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }  
}
```

ViewController2:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
var userURL: URL!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: userURL)
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "secondLoad")

}
```

TODO:// You will want to check if the user entered a valid URL before sending him to the next page. Here is a pod that can do that for you:
https://github.com/adamwaite/Validator

If it is not a valid URL, show an error pop-up and let the user enter a correct URL, otherwise don't send him to the ViewController2.

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll have a look and attempt to integrate this as this incorporates the first load and second load that I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry really struggling getting this working.
I've created a new project 
ViewController1.swift
ViewController2.swift
Main.Storyboard

I'm getting the error 
`Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'URL!'` 

on

`vc.userURL = urlTextField.text!` on line 30 of ViewController1.swift

Comment: I can upload my project if that helps? Sorry for the questions I'm pretty new to this

Comment: Oops, I accidentally forgot to assing a URL instead of String. I edited my answer, and it should work now.

Comment: I am glad I was helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

hey @Danny Here is Solution.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBOutlet var txtField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func NextBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        vc.passUrl = txtField.text!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }  
}
```

//Next Class Is.

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
var passUrl = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(passUrl)
    let websiteUrl = URL(string: "http://\(passUrl)")
    //let websiteUrl = URL(string: "http://tablet.brainsplurge.co.uk")//open to check

    var urlRequest: URLRequest? = nil
    if let anUrl = websiteUrl {
        urlRequest = URLRequest(url: anUrl)
    }
    if let aRequest = urlRequest {
        webView.loadRequest(aRequest)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Saxena, I've just tried this and struggling to get this to work on my end.  I've scrapped the code I had and started with yours but when I'm pressing enter after entering the url it's not going on to the second view controller it's just staying on that one.

Comment: Just Download and Use.
https://github.com/testingraahul/stringOnWebview

Comment: It is not sending it to the next view because most probably you don't have a navigationController embeded into your viewController. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you for creating & sending that! I've had a look but if I enter the url (minus http://) in the text field and click next it never loads.  

If I uncomment the second let websiteurl and try using the test function that loads up fine

Comment: if you add http with str
like this https://www.google.com simply change this line.
         let websiteUrl = URL(string: passUrl)//close when open below line
 ok

Comment: I you Enter text with http, then you replace this line no 21 to this **         let websiteUrl = URL(string: passUrl)//close when open below line
**

Comment: Sweet that works! Thank you so much for your help and code!